# Symfony Doctrine исключить установку индексов в relationship

Tags: symfony2, symfony, doctrine, doctrine2

Можно ли описать сущность (Dotrine Entity) так, чтобы при генерации схемы не создавался индекс в таблице?

Есть сущность Mistakes.php:

```
/**
 * @var Trainings
 * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="Acme\TrainingBundle\Entity\Trainings")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="training_id", referencedColumnName="id", unique=false)
 */
private $training;
```

После добавления сущности `Trainings` в сущность `Mistakes` в PHPMyAdmin можно видеть следующую таблицу:

[image: PhpMyAdmin]

Если добавить сущность с уже добавленным `Training_id` - происходит SQL ошибка - дублирование ключа `training_id`!

Как разрешить дублирование в данном случае?

Comment: Схема построена именно по тем аннотациям, что указаны? По-умолчанию в Doctrine все связи опциональны. Скорее всего, Ваша схема была построена до того, как вносились последние изменения в аннотации или маппинг идет из yml/xml.

Comment: Удалил всю базу, сделал update scheme --force
В Repourse/config/doctrine (вроде так) ничего нету. Видимо генерируется по данным аннотациям.
Но все равно если дублируется training_id, то все катится вниз - снова ошибка "Дублирование по ключу training_id"

Answer (score 1):

Ограничение накладывается БД, т.к. схема БД была создана на основании описания моделей для Doctrine.

В вашей сущности `Mistakes` необходимо заменить описание типа связи с `OneToOne` на `ManyToOne` для свойства `training`.

После чего обновить схему БД либо вручную, либо командой `app/console d:s:u --force`.